# Tx Rx Arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

first of all let me thank you all , you have been of great help.
So, my problem is the next , i have note counter machine i need to read the data from the machine to the arduino , as bytes or ascii , just some readble data .
The machine is connected on the arduino via 2 pins , tx and rx and the data i am getting is not readble and kind of wierd , and one more question do i need some kind of serial shiled or no ?Because right now it is connected with just 2 wires . Thank you

```
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>

// AltSoftSerial always uses these pins:
//
// Board          Transmit  Receive   PWM Unusable
// -----          --------  -------   ------------
// Teensy 3.0 & 3.1  21        20         22
// Teensy 2.0         9        10       (none)
// Teensy++ 2.0      25         4       26, 27
// Arduino Uno        9         8         10
// Arduino Leonardo   5        13       (none)
// Arduino Mega      46        48       44, 45
// Wiring-S           5         6          4
// Sanguino          13        14         12

AltSoftSerial altSerial;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // wait for Arduino Serial Monitor to open
  Serial.println("AltSoftSerial Test Begin");
  altSerial.begin(9600);
}
byte rx_byte =0 ;
char text ;
char hex;
void loop() {
  if (altSerial.available()) {
    // get the byte from the software serial port


   rx_byte = altSerial.read();
    // send a byte to the software serial port
    //altSerial.println(text);
  Serial.print(rx_byte, HEX);

}
     //Serial.println("TUKA SUM");
      //text = altSerial.read();

    //hex=(text);

  //Serial.print(text); 
    //Serial.write(text);
  // Serial.println(text);
```

Comment: What is the code? And what is the weird output?

Comment: Please provide a link to the note counter you are using.

Comment: Why are you using soft serial and not 'hardware' serial? What is the output? And are you sure 9600 is the correct speed?

Comment: AltSoftSerial Test Begin
00FE0F00000000000000000000000000000140B50000000000000000009C0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000083000830000B4AFB400002F90008000007F0042000091000E700E2FF00000F001E00FE0080000000000007DFC00F0000000008000FF

Comment: This is what i am getting , and link is http://souqmega.com/product/nc3500-ma-value-counting-machine/

Comment: and yeah i am sure because i can set the baud rate in the machine ,

Comment: A picture is of no use. Is there a manual or datasheet you can link to?

Comment: Is the connection to the machine UART or RS-232?

Comment: baud rate of what? the RX and TX pins are for external display

Comment: https://manualzz.com/doc/6360685/nc-3500-series-multi-currency-banknote-counter

Comment: Are you using the 9 pin or the 5 pin port?

Comment: try interchanging tx and rx pins it worked for me after interchanging those pins

Comment: I am using the 9 pin port , and from the tx and rx on the serial cable i am conecting them to the rx and tx on arduino , or 8 and 9 in the sketch , there is no shiled on the arduino for serial cable , just two wires .

Comment: You are still just printing human readable hexadecimal characters, just like in your earlier questions. And your output consists only of characters, that are used to represent hexadecimal values in human readable form. So what output were you expecting from it? As I see the code, you cannot get other output than this hex represetation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 9-pin port is designed for connecting to a printer. It uses the RS-232 protocol, not UART.

You cannot connect it directly to an Arduino - you must connect it via a MAX232 adaptor board.

**Disconnect the cable immediately - the voltage levels of RS-232 are likely to do permanent damage to the Arduino.**

Comment: Yeah i saw it somewhere , i disconeteced it , so in conclusion there is no way just two wires from serial cable to tx and rx on arduino ?

Comment: Nope. You need to transform the voltage levels from -10V/+10V to +5V/0V.

Comment: So without MAX232 adaptor board i can do the thing i want , Okey , thank you a  lot .